# Joined tables single row with desired results

Tags: sql, oracle, join, foreign-key-relationship

First of all, I know that this is a case of a bad design, but I am just wondering how can I get single sql result from the jointure with the desired infos.

So it's a simple exemple, 2 tables connected with ids:

```
 TableA                   TableB

 id   code                id   tableA_id (FK)   start   end 
---- -------             ---- ---------------- ------- ------        
 1    codeA               1    2                NY      null
 2    codeB               2    2                null    LA
```

So line 2 in `TableA` has 2 corresponding lines in `TableB`.

**Desired result:**

```
 tableA_code   tableB_start   tableB_end
------------- -------------- ------------
 codeB         NY             LA
```

So in the result in need to group the 2 lines from the table B into one line and eliminate the null values.

Comment: Either an extra self join, or a group by.

Comment: yes group by will be the answer

Comment: Are there always two entries in `TableB` for each entry in `TableA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query :

```
select A.code, B1.start, B2.end
from TableB B1, TableB B2, TableA A
where B1.tableA_id = B2.tableA_id
and B1.tableA_id = A.id
and B1.start is not null and B2.end is not null
```

Comment: thanks Mr Thorynique its simple and perfect and even without a group by

Answer (score 0):

```
Let me know if this works for you

SELECT A.code,
  MAX(B.STRT) STRT,
  MAX(B.END)
END
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS A_ID,'CODE A' AS CODE FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS A_ID,'CODE B' AS CODE FROM DUAL
  )A,
  (SELECT 1 AS B_ID,2 AS A_ID,'NY' STRT, NULL AS END FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS B_ID,2 AS A_ID, NULL STRT, 'LA' AS END FROM DUAL
  )B
WHERE A.A_ID = B.A_ID
GROUP BY A.code;
```